# Scroll to top then fixed glitchy on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, scroll

First post :)

I've got an element (image #logo) that starts off 120px from the top of a page, scrolls to the top then becomes fixed.

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>120){
        $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
});
```

It's working great on desktop browsers, but on an iPhone it seem the CSS change only happens once I lift my finger. While scrolling, the element stays wherever it was. Ruins the effect I was trying to create and looks bad. Anyway to get the CSS adapted while touch scrolling?

Comment: Scroll? I think you mean move() instead... A scroll is to move the whole content of a window.

Comment: Nope. I mean scroll. The image is 120px from the top, scrolls with the rest of the page and then is fixed once it hits the top.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. I guess it was not phrased the way I would have phrased it... Anyway... Have you tried to have a fixed element to see whether that would work by itself on that iPhone. If fixed is not implemented (at least not properly) then it would make sense that it would fail with jQuery too...

Comment: Yes, and it all works correctly on the iPhone, but only once you lift your finger after scrolling. The fixed element is working, the jquery is working, but the element scrolls off the screen and then jumps back (fixed to the top) once you lift your finger.